# Page Layout Scrolls Off The Screen

Tags: css

Having a problem with this site, http://www.keefebartels.com/. The page looks OK but you'll notice you can scroll to the right. Not sure what's causing this. I thought it would be a weird  issue that I'm missing. Any ideas?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: You have some elements with a defined width in pixel (I found, for instance, 1300 and 2000). However, as suggested by @j08691 , you need to edit your post, since its quality is too low right now

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add `overflow:hidden` to the `.textwidget` element in the sidebar; it's child element `.calc` is positioned relative and as a result it's flying off the screen, forcing the scrollbar to appear.

Comment: What about "Injury Claim Calclator" link.  Don't you want that to be visible on the page?  This solution hides in from being visible on the page.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the CSS associated with the following code:

```
<div class="textwidget">
    <a class="calc" href="http://injuryclaimcalculator.us/">Injury Claim Calculator</a>
</div>
```

It shows that the calc class is getting the following property.  This is causing for the link to be placed 900px to the right and therefore causing you to be able to scroll to the right.

```
right: -900px;
```

Removing the above code from the CSS will fix the site.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your style.css file, find .calc class and remove right:-900px;
Fixed!!